# Проблема с yum(Centos 6)

Tags: centos, package

Собственно такая проблема:

```
[root@s1 ~]# yum install lxde
Подготовка к установке
Пакет lxde недоступен.
Ошибка: Выполнять нечего
```

Какова причина её возникновения?

Бывает возникает даже с элементарными пакетами!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этого пакета просто нет в стандартном репозитарии Centos 6. Поискать где есть - можно здесь [pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/)